# Como acessar os dados do "nivel" mais interno de um JSON?

Tags: java, android, json

Eu precisava de uma forma para poder acessar o "nível" mais interno do JSON abaixo:  (nome, valor, última consulta e fonte)

```
{
    "status": true,
    "valores": {
        "USD": {
            "nome": "Dólar",
            "valor": 2.333,
            "ultima_consulta": 1386349203,
            "fonte": "UOL Economia - http://economia.uol.com.br/cotacoes/"
        }
    }
}
```

Estou tentando acessar dessa forma, mas ele cai na `JSONException`:

```
   try {

        String resposta = ar.run(url); //resposta contém o JSON que retorna do WS
        Log.i("RETORNO: -------", resposta);
        JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(resposta);
        JSONArray ja;
        ja = jo.getJSONArray(resposta);
        moedas.setAbreviacao(ja.getJSONObject(0).getString("USD"));
        Log.i("RESULTADO: ", moedas.getAbreviacao());
        Log.i("RESULTADO: ", moedas.getDescricao());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();;
    } finally {
        dialog.dismiss();

    }
```

Até tentei usar a GSON, mas também não obtive sucesso.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não há nenhum array no JSON que você tem - você só tem objetos (e valores primitivos - strings, números, etc). Você precisará acessá-los como tal, algo como o código abaixo:

```
JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(resposta);
JSONObject valores = jo.getJSONObject("valores");
JSONObject usd = valores.getJSONObject("USD");
String nome = usd.getString("nome");
double valor = usd.getDouble("valor");
long ultimaConsulta = usd.getLong("ultima_consulta");
String fone = usd.getString("fone");
```

Comment: Funcionou. Só precisei editar a linha:   `JSONObject usd = jo.getJSONObject("USD");`  para `JSONObject usd = valores.getJSONObject("USD");   Obrigado!

Comment: Isso - copy/paste error. Corrigido.